# Installing Deepin Desktop Environment on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ppa, repository, add-apt-repository

I tried to install the Deepin Desktop Environment by following the instructions given in several websites, but when I started adding the PPA by executing the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
```

I got these messages:

```
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                     
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu eoan Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done         
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Are there any other repositories for installing the Deepin Desktop Environment on Ubuntu?